# working data from/to PHP and jquery, possible?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm looking at a [domain registration site](https://www.website.ws/orderflow/index.dhtml?sponsor=gditraffic&src=DSP&last_page=DSP) that looks like it uses jquery to process users data inputed and to register domains.

What I was wondering is if it's possible for users to be able to fill in data on a form on my website and then when the user is ready to complete payment, be taken to the actually domain registration site where all the data they typed in on my site will be posted to the domain reg site.

So basically, the users fills in a load of info on my site, AND attempts to check for domain availability on my site. Once the users has found the domain they want, they will be redirected over to the actual domain reg site where all their info will be posted.

Now I know if the domain reg site used PHP to process all the stuff, it wouldn't be a problem. But they don't use PHP.

Do you guys reckon this could be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this would be possible in any amount of time that would make it worth it to you. Without knowing any of their back-end code, it's going to be extraordinarily difficult. Edit: I should add that I did look through some of their jQuery code and it looks as though they're using ajax .post() to submit data. Where this data goes and what responses are expected is anyone's guess, though...

That said... there are quite a few domain registrars that offer real APIs to let you do what you want... or even let you go one step further and offer the ability to register domains directly through your website. Sometimes you can set your own price, as well.

Here are links to some of these APIs:

- Namecheap: http://developer.namecheap.com/docs/
- GoDaddy: http://www.godaddy.com/reseller/domain-reseller-api.aspx
- eNom: http://www.enom.com/resellers/Interfaceinfo.asp

I'd personally recommend NameCheap, but for the purposes of your question, any of these should do.

Answer (score 0):

I can't make any promises but say you used jquery ajax to pull in the form the would have to fill out. Said form would then be on your client side so in theory I think you could use their input ids to fill out the form using javascript/jquery. All this would technically be client side. To bad that other site does not have an api for purchases.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control over the domain registration site? There are many ways you can send the user's input over to that site, but of course it has to be looking for this posted data and know how to handle it. PHP is not necessary to handle the data that is passed in. For example, if you send your info to the domain registration site via a form GET method, the info will become part of the URL, which can be accessed and parsed via javascripts window.location property.